# asp.net Identity 2.1 sometimes fail to log in

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity

Visual studio 2013, Asp.net Identity 2.1.0

Most of the time user can log in without problem, but sometime user cannot log in. This is hard to reproduce. When user failed to log in, the menu (that only shows when user logged in) do not appear, and the `<LoggedInTemplate>` still shows "Log in" instead of "Log off". When I check Event Viewer, I found the following. Is this a bug of Web API 2.1? Does anyone have the same problem? Is there a workaround?

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: HttpException 
Exception message: Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.
   at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.SetHeader(String name, String value, Boolean replace)
   at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.Set(String name, String value)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.Set(String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.set_Item(String key, String[] value)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.SetHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2 headers, String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.AppendHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2 headers, String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.HeaderDictionary.AppendValues(String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.ResponseCookieCollection.Append(String key, String value, CookieOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseGrantAsync>d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseCoreAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<TeardownAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
Request URL: http://localhost:55108/ 
Request path: / 
User host address: ::1 
User: xxx 
Is authenticated: True 
Authentication Type: ApplicationCookie 
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\xxx 

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 5 
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\xxx 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.SetHeader(String name, String value, Boolean replace)
at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.Set(String name, String value)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.Set(String key, String[] values)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.set_Item(String key, String[] value)
at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.SetHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2 headers, String key, String[] values)
at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.AppendHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2 headers, String key, String[] values)
at Microsoft.Owin.HeaderDictionary.AppendValues(String key, String[] values)
at Microsoft.Owin.ResponseCookieCollection.Append(String key, String value, CookieOptions options)
at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseGrantAsync>d__b.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseCoreAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<TeardownAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: The problem is that at the point where your user is logging in, you have already written to the response stream somehow.  You probably have some code somewhere that does Response.Write(), and this cannot happen before the login cookie gets sent.

Comment: vow, that's exactly the case. Thank you! in my login function there is a try-catch wrapping everything, and Response.Write() is in the catch:    `try{...}catch(Exception error){            Response.Write(error.Message);}`